# What is scanning udp ports 8610-8612 on Debian Buster?

Tags: debian, nmap, psad

I've got several computers with Debian Buster (Gnome) installed. Thanks to psad tool I realized that all of them frequently (at least several times a day) scan udp ports 8610-8612 in the local network.

I wonder what is the purpose of this? What package or service does that? DuckDuckGoing didn't help and I have no idea how to get into this.

I blocked outgoing connections on those ports on some of the computers using firewall and didn't notice any malfunction of any part of the system.

Below you can see a part of psad-alert e-mail:

```
         Danger level: [3] (out of 5)

    Scanned UDP ports: [8610-8612: 4 packets, Nmap: -sU]
       iptables chain: INPUT (prefix "[UFW BLOCK]"), 4 packets
```

There is something that may (or may not) be relevant - psad alerts show ipv6 of the source and target, while we generally use only ipv4 in the LAN.

Comment: Could be anything, trying to look for a service on that port, also you can try to put a process with netcat/nc listening on that ports and dump the output in order to see the layer7 that the source is using.

Comment: Could be related to this report of  Canon MFP devices sending multicast traffic on port 8610: https://community.usa.canon.com/t5/Wireless-Networking/Multicasts-from-Canon-software-on-UDP-8610/td-p/260951

Comment: Could it be Avahi? Just a random idea. What does tcpdump show?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not using Debian or Ubuntu so I can't check this, but it might be related to the printing service CUPS. There is a [confirmed bug in Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/1671974) which reports a problem with the `cups-browsed` service sending a large amount of UDP requests on ports 8610 and 8612.

You could try to stop any CUPS service and see if the scans stop.

Comment: Thanks for the lead - I'm going to check this and let you know about the outcome.

Comment: I followed the thread you linked and my problem looks exactly as described there. Funny thing which I read there is that connecting any USB device triggers port scanning  - I didn't recognize this before. Unfortunately the issue is not resolved... But it's probably not `cups`-related after all (I tried disabling `cups-browsed`, didn't help).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. A comment at the [Ubuntu bug page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/1671974/comments/16) (linked by [dr01](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/34039/dr01)) lead me to `colord` (instead of `cups`) and stopping `colord` seems to have fixed it.